# Image Enhancement in Flutter: Applying Brightness and Contrast Adjustments

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently developing an app that allows users to upload their bills and other documents. My goal is to enhance these uploaded images to make them appear as if they were actual PDF documents, similar to the example shown below:

[image]

I was able to create this example using a different application. However, I'm now seeking guidance on how to implement a similar effect in Flutter for images uploaded by users.

Could you please provide insights, code examples, or suggestions on how to achieve this in Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

I researched this and came up with a simple app as a starting point.

First, you'll need to import the following dependencies:

```yaml
  image_picker: ^1.0.4 // to select an image from the gallery or from the caemra.

  image: ^4.0.17 // to apply image filters and enhancements.

  pdf: ^3.10.4 // to convert the image to pdf.

  path_provider: ^2.1.1 // to provide a directory to store the files.

  open_file: ^3.3.2 // to open the PDF file.
```

You can use the `image` package to apply a filter to the image:

```dart
  img.Image enhanceImage(img.Image image) {
    // Adjust contrast, brightness, and gamma
    img.adjustColor(image, contrast: 1.5, brightness: 10);
    return image;
  }


  img.Image applyFilter(File imageFile, String filter) {
    final image = img.decodeImage(imageFile.readAsBytesSync())!;
    switch (filter) {
      case 'Enhanced':
        return enhanceImage(image);
      case 'Grayscale':
        return img.grayscale(image);
      case 'Sepia':
        return img.sepia(image);
      default:
        return image;
    }
  }
```

You can then convert the image to PDF using the `pdf` package:

```dart
  Future<File> convertToPdf(img.Image image) async {
    final pdf = pw.Document();
    final pdfImage = pw.MemoryImage(img.encodeJpg(image));
    pdf.addPage(
      pw.Page(
        build: (pw.Context context) => pw.Center(
          child: pw.Image(pdfImage),
        ),
      ),
    );
    final pdfBytes = pdf.save();
    final Directory documentDirectory =
        await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String documentPath = documentDirectory.path;
    final File receiptFile = File('$documentPath/example.pdf');
    receiptFile.writeAsBytesSync(List.from(await pdfBytes));
    return receiptFile;
  }
```

[More filters](https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/blob/main/doc/filters.md).

Here is the `main.dart` file: https://gist.github.com/omarhuss/37b1e08ac45fff95e8b376209c20118c

I hope that helps as a starting point!

Comment: how to convert these image to file?